# Mysql table replace or delete row

Tags: mysql, image, upload

I don't know about how sql work. I have an image table in sql for product. Should I delete and upload new image or replace the existing row? Which is better for long term and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on the table purpose.

If this table is just to show each `IMG_ITEM_ID` path, then you don't need to save history, you can just update the old picture.

If this table should save history - To track things like old bugs, or to see what was the image in some point, the you should close the old picture, and insert a new row, but in this I advise you to add two columns - `START_DATE,END_DATE` which will allow you to monitor the history properly.

Comment: Thanks sagi. I didn't consider to add start_date and end_date before.
Look like replacing the image is more suite for me as I'll not save history.
Thank you.